# How to $expand Child entity first then Parent entity in Odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have 2 entities Student and courses  as below.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Student_Id{ get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Course> courses{ get; set; }
   }

public class Courses
{
    [Key]
    public int Course_Id{ get; set; }

    public int Student_Id{ get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CourseName{ get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

   }
```

The following $expand is working as expected.

```
http://localhost:61565/Odata/Student?$select=Student_Id,FirstName &$expand=Courses($select=Course_Id,CourseName)
```

Is there anyway I can $expand child entity "Courses" first and then Parent "Student" 
Even If I add the below code

```
   public ICollection<Student> Students{ get; set; }
```

to the courses. It is throwing error when I use $expand option.

Is there any way can we set navigation properties bidirectionally on both parent and child entity-sets or any other way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access in Bi-directional add ForiegnKey for Student_id in Courses as below.

```
  public class Courses
{
 [Key]
public int Course_Id{ get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("Student")]
public int Student_Id{ get; set; }

 [StringLength(100)]
public string CourseName{ get; set; }

 [StringLength(10)]
public string Duration { get; set; }

public virtual Student Student{ get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the Course(s) class should contain an ICollection of Student.
I think the URL should be something like this:

```
http://localhost:61565/Odata/Student
    ?$select=Student_Id,FirstName
    &$expand=Courses(
        $select=Course_Id,CourseName;
        $expand=Students(
            $select=Student_Id,FirstName))
```

Here is an example on a live OData endpoint:

```
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service-v4/odata/Categories
    ?$top=20
    &$select=CategoryName
    &$expand=Products(
        $select=ProductName,Category;
        $expand=Category(
            $select=CategoryName))
```

What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the example, It helped me. To fix this issue we have to add ForiegnKey constraint for Student_Id in Courses then it work.